# Can I variabalize an object like a dictionary reference in python

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment

I have a series of dictionaries that hold values that I want to combine at the end .  The combination is messy so I can't just combine the dictionaries I have to work based on keys and make some careful choices.  When I created the dictionaries I created them in the form item#Dict  expecting to do something like

```
for value in ['8','10','11','12','13','14','15','18','19','20']:
    dictName='item'+value+'Dict'
```

but as I quickly learned dictName is a string not a reference to my dictionary.

Is there a way to make reference to my dictionary using some pattern type approach?

I do see that the alternative is to add all of my dictionaries to a list as I create them and then iterate through the list- that solution only occurred to me as I was writing this question.  But I am interested in knowing if there is some way to implement my original approach.

Thanks

Comment: Your original approach is wrong.  It won't even work in Python 3.  Use your new approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval()` could do it:

```
>>> d = {'a':'first', 'b':'second'}
>>> d == eval('d')
True
```

But be careful!  It's a slippery slope.  Using `eval()` creates security flaws, it's slow, and it encourages spaghetti code.

The introspective methods `getattr` and `locals()` are similarly risky.  They are powerful, and they let you do things that would take lines and lines of C++.  But they should only be used when absolutely required.

In your case, the best solution is a dictionary of dictionaries, as others have already answered.

Comment: Thanks I had forgotten about eval() and you are right- I stared at my code last night and decided a better approach was needed.  I checked your answer because it does do exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [locals](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) function to get a dictionary containing variables in the current local scope:

```
>>> var0 = 7
>>> var1 = 3
>>> var2 = 4
>>> var3 = 5
>>> for i in range(4):
...    print 'var', i, 'is', locals()['var%d' % i]
... 
var 0 is 7
var 1 is 3
var 2 is 4
var 3 is 5
```

Although, I don't really recommend doing this. I would suggest putting your variables into a dictionary or a list, like you alluded to in your post.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful and I appreciate that you took the time

Answer (score 1):

You can get the named dictionaries this way if they are attributes on an object, using [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html).

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.item1dict = {}
        self.item2dict = {}

    def print_all_dicts(self):
        for x in [1,2]:
            print getattr(self, 'item{0}dict'.format(x))
```

Just be careful with this sort of metaprogramming, as it can be a slippery slope into the land of obfuscated code.

Comment: Is there any other kind of code for a guy like me??  Thanks this is helpful.