# searching python lists dynamically

Tags: python, list, search

I am looking to consolidate a function which I know can be improved.

I have a series of global lists, which I add to, and add the number of lists regularly.

In this function, I can search for an input character and return the list number and location in the list. Unfortunately, each time I add a new list, I also have to add a new nested try /except ValueError with the new list name.

I'm certain that someone with more coding experience than me can come up with a way to recursively call this function and search without nesting these.
Ideally I guess I would specify how many "Listx" lists to search with a function that accepts a string and an integer?

```
def findInLists(inputString):

    line = 0
    output = 0

    try:
        output = List1.index(inputString)
    except ValueError:
        line += 1
        try:
            output = List2.index(inputString)
        except ValueError:
            line += 1
            try:
                output = List3.index(inputString)
            except ValueError:
                line += 1
                try:
                    output = List4.index(inputString)
                except ValueError:
                    output = -1
    return str(line) + str(output)
```

Comment: What about using nested lists?

Comment: Do you mean for  output = List.index(inputString) to be  output = List2.index(inputString)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying after your clarification - so you are willing to specify a fixed number of lists before the search:

```
def _search_lists(phrase,numb_of_lists):
    for n in range(1, numb_of_lists + 1):
        list_name = "list" + str(n)
        list_to_search = eval(list_name)
        if search phrase in list_to_search:
            return n, list_to_search.index(search_phrase)
    return 0,0
```

the return is the list number and the index position, if not in any list then (0,0)

Note, many people warn about the dangers of using the eval function but in this case, presuming it is your code you should be fine.

Comment: This is a really clean approach - I didn't realize I could use a string to call on the lists I had generated. - thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem a long time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748596/can-i-variabalize-an-object-like-a-dictionary-reference-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid the nesting, use early `return`s:

```
def findInLists(inputString):

    line = 0
    output = 0

    try:
        output = List1.index(inputString)
        return str(line) + str(output)
    except ValueError:
        line += 1
    try:
        output = List2.index(inputString)
        return str(line) + str(output)
    except ValueError:
        line += 1
    try:
        output = List3.index(inputString)
        return str(line) + str(output)
    except ValueError:
        line += 1
    try:
        output = List4.index(inputString)
        return str(line) + str(output)
    except ValueError:
        output = -1
    return str(line) + str(output)
```

Now this is still a lot of duplicated logic, isn't it? But it's now easier to refactor it further into a `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to search a list of lists. So you should make a list of lists, in stead of using suffixes on variable names.

So something along these lines should fit your needs:

```
def find_it(lists, val):
    idxVal = -1
    idxList = -1
    for l in lists:
        try:
            f = l.index(val)
        except: 
            pass
    return idxList, idxVal 

 listIndex, valueIndex = find_it([List1, List2, List3], "foo")
```

Of course this is only one of the many possible solutions (you could do it recursively, tail-first, use `reduce()`, etc etc)

Generally, if you feel like you have a number of things of the same type, you should use lists. Suffixing your variable names is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
list1= ["foo"];
list2= ["foo"];
list3= ["foo"];
list4= ["foo", "baz"];

def findInLists(inputString):
    lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4];
    output = -1;
    for i, each in enumerate(lists):
        try:
            output = each.index(inputString)
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return str(i+1) + str(output)
```

Try it out:https://repl.it/CQn3/3